# Selmer Group versus Selmer Variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, abelian-varieties, galois-representations, galois-cohomology

For an abelian variety $A$, the $p$-adic Selmer group is defined to be the subset of $H^1(G_k,H_1^{et}(A;\mathbb{Q}_{p}))$ whose restriction to $G_{k_v}$ is in the image of $A(k_v)$ for all places $v$ of $k$.

[Minhyong Kim's paper](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahmki/alb.pdf) states on its third page (p.91) that his Selmer varieties generalize $\mathbb{Q}_p$ Selmer groups of elliptic curves. As I understand it, his Selmer variety would refer to the subset of $H^1(G_k,H_1^{et}(A;\mathbb{Q}_{p}))$ that is unramified for $v \nmid p$ and crystalline at $v \mid p$ (assuming the abelian variety has good reduction there).

Is it clear that these two definitions are equivalent? Why is this true?

Comment: I think you are asking why the Bloch-Kato Selmer group $H^1_f$ is equal to the usual Selmer group defined by the local image of the Kummer map. If so this is Example 3.11 in Bloch-Kato in Grothendieck Festschrift.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should read the Bloch--Kato paper in the Grothendieck Festschrift. This was, I believe, the first paper to consider Selmer groups of Galois representations defined by local conditions coming from p-adic Hodge theory (e.g. crystalline at p).

The definition you quote from Kim is exactly the Bloch--Kato definition of the Selmer group; and Bloch and Kato prove in their paper that in the case of abelian varieties their definition recovers the classical Selmer group.

Comment: I also found this resource http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/bellaiche.pdf, which discusses this fact in Proposition 2.13 on p.31.

Comment: Also see http://web.stanford.edu/~tonyfeng/L14.pdf for a possibly better explanation of the proof of this point.